# How to generate link that will openapp /redirect to appstore and pass some data to the app?

Tags: branch.io

Just started to read branch.io documentation and can't find how do that.

My case:
I have a server on which I generate emails and send emails to users. Server is written in Node.js (javascript environment). I just want to generate link that will **either open** specific app (ios/android) or **redirect** to appstore (I want to paste this link in each email). In both cases I want to pass some data (like `{"code":"xxx"}`) to the opened/installed application.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: sorry that you're having trouble finding this info! Fortunately what you've described is exactly what Branch does best.

Here is a list of items you'll need to run through:

1. [Sign up for Branch](https://dashboard.branch.io/).
2. [Complete the initial dashboard setup process](https://start.branch.io/).
3. [Integrate the Branch SDK into your iOS/Android app](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/).
4. [Read about how links are configured](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/).
5. [Use the API to generate links on your Node.js server](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api) (alternatively, depending on how you have things set up, you might be able to make use of [the javascript SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking)).